# AWS clone user and permissions using AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to programmatically clone IAM users. In order for me to test permissions on behalf of other users, I want a way to create test users with the same permissions and group memberships as another real user. I can do this using the AWS console but I could not find AWS CLI / terraform way of doing this.

Comment: in aws cli, you will need to create user, apply policies(already present) to the user and put the user in group. If I undertand correctly, do you want this? these will be three different operations for each user.

Comment: Yes, I can do that using multiple AWS CLI commands but this is possible with a single click on the AWS console(one of the options under add user workflow), I was expecting that AWS CLI must allow that option. Thanks !!